# C++/CLI: Cannot see referenced assemblies without using #include

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, interop

We have two C++/CLI projects, a pure CLR project and a mixed-mode project that exists to provide our unmanaged codebase access to the pure CLR project. We are having trouble getting the mixed-mode project to see symbols defined in the pure CLR project.

Specifically we have a form, call it MainForm, defined in the purely-managed project. It's a typical C++/CLI Windows Form:

MainForm.h:

```
public ref class MainForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    MainForm(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here

    }
    ...
};
```

Our mixed-mode "wrapper" project tries to use it, like so:

ManagedDialogProvider.h:

```
namespace ManagedWrapper
{
    public ref class ManagedDialogProvider
    {
        static void ShowDialog()
        {
             OurManagedComponents::MainForm^ form = gcnew OurManagedComponents::MainForm();
        }
    };
}
```

(We then have a C++/MFC class in the mixed-mode project, CManagedDialogProvider, that calls ManagedDialogProvider so that our unmanaged code can use it. The error isn't occurring there, however.)

When I try building the mixed-mode project, it tells me that MainForm is not a member of OurManagedComponents. (Error in ManagedWrapper::ManagedDialogProvider::ShowDialog().)

Notes:

- The mixed-mode project has a reference to the managed project.
- I have tried using an #include at the top of the managed wrapper class *instead* of a reference, and while this compiled, I then couldn't load the form due to its resources not being found. I backed out of this solution as it's not accepted practice if I understand correctly; .NET projects should reference each other via assembly references only.
- I've verified that the managed class is accessible (public).
- I've checked the Object Browser to ensure that OurManagedComponents is visible and contains MainForm.

Any ideas?  The same mixed-mode project has no trouble wrapping C# managed components, but when I tried using that same approach for this C++/CLI managed component, these issues appeared.

Comment: As the error is about `OurManagedComponents::MainForm` you should probably post a reduced version of the class.

Comment: Also please give more information about `CMainDialogProvider`.

Comment: Use Object Browser to verify that the class is visible and that you used the right namespace name.  Consider an oops like OurManagedComponents::OurManagedComponents::MainForm.  Double-check with, say, a C# project.

Comment: @Hans: Browsing objects by namespace, and I see {} OurManagedComponents, and inside that MainForm as a publicly-accessible class, and inside that, a public constructor.  The intellisense suggests I'm using the right object as well--it was able to autocomplete the OurManagedComponents::MainForm. But then I build and it says MainForm isn't a member of OurManagedComponents. :(

Comment: @Hans: Also double-checked by calling one of our C# forms instead, but that built and ran fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that OurManagedComponents::MainForm had no implementation file (.cpp); it only had a .h file. So naturally, MainForm was never actually built or linked in to the project. (Interestingly, the object browser still showed OurManagedComponents::MainForm and the project still built just fine; it must see declared types regardless of whether they are implemented).  What can I say, I've been using C# too long :-)

Once I created a MainForm.cpp (empty but for *include "MainForm.h"*) and rebuilt, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ManagedWrapper::ManagedDialogProvider::ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Sorry--thats what I did, the example is simplified/contrived from our actual code. Fixed example :)

Comment: Update: The above references my example CManagedDialogProvider class, which I've removed from the question since the error wasn't occurring there but rather in the .NET ManagedDialogProvider class.

Answer (score 0):

> We then have an unmanaged class in
>   that same project that calls
>   ManagedDialogProvider so that our
>   unmanaged code can use it.

Unmanaged (native) code can not reach to managed code without proper callbacks.
Think about the code below.

```
// CMainDialogProvider.h

typedef void (*ShowDialogNativeCB)() ;

class CMainDialogProvider
{
//..
public:
  ShowDialogNativeCB nativeCB;
//..

}

// ManagedDialogProvider.h
#include "CMainDialogProvider.h"

public delegate void ShowDialogClrCB ();

namespace ManagedWrapper
{
   // ....
   //somehow you have to provide the ShowDialog() function as a callback;
   ShowDialogClrCB ^ clrCB = gcnew ShowDialogClrCB(&ManagedDialogProvider::ShowDialog());
   GCHandle clrCBhandle = GCHandle::Alloc(clrCB);
   // to prevent the garbage collection of delegate.
   // but this must be freed later. 
   IntPtr ip = Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(clrCB);
   // Lets say Instance is an instance of CMainDialogProvider.
   Instance->nativeCB = static_cast<ShowDialogNativeCB>(ip.ToPointer());
   //...
}

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CManagedDialogProvider.h" // C++ class
#include "ManagedDialogProvider.h"  // .NET ref class

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CManagedDialogProvider, CObject)

void CManagedDialogProvider::ShowDialog()
{
   if(nativeCB != NULL)
     nativeCB();
}
```

Comment: CMainDialogProvider is declared like a standard C++ class but it calls managed C++ classes. We have similar wrapper classes around C# components and they work fine.  (It's not to be confused with the unmanaged client code that will _use_ CMainDialogProvider; _that_ code is unmanaged.)

Comment: Sorry for not specifying--the wrapper class is in the mixed-mode project having CLR support. I know it the approach works because we have other, similarly-defined C++ wrapper classes that call into referenced C#.net components, without using any callbacks.  The problem isn't occurring in CManagedDialogProvider but rather ManagedDialogProvider. This wasn't clear from my example--I've removed all but the two classes involved from the question.

Comment: @System.Cats.Lol: Well I can tell one more thing but it may not be related to the error. Can it be an encapsulation problem? `ShowDialog()` is not public. Maybe `MainForm` is also declared as `public private` or just `private`.

Comment: @sad_man: MainForm is public, and ShowDialog() is just the standard Windows.Form method (public). Good thing to check though.

Comment: @System.Cats.Lol: Then lets call @Hans Passant. :) He will tell.

Comment: @sad_man he had a good suggestion, but alas this remains a mystery!